# Create jQuery table

Tags: jquery

I have created a datepicker by using jQuery. Now I want to create a table. Can anyone tell me an effective method to create a table? I want to use it as I created datepicker. I am looking for a method to define table column names as parameters. I have found a couple of plugin but they either have so many details or no details at all.. If there is no method or way to accomplish this, just a small explanation is alright.

I am looking for something like this to create a table:

```
var dates = $('#datepicker').datepicker({
//defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
minDate: new Date(),
maxDate: '+2y',
numberOfMonths: 3,
beforeShowDay: isNotAvailable,

onSelect: function(selectedDate){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/). You didn't mention the plugins you tried, so I can't tell whether this is one of them. If it is, you should take a second look, since jqGrid is very powerful. It has the features you mentioned, is quite easy to work with in spite of its richness, and is very well documented.

Comment: Hi Marcelo,thanks for answering my question. I have decided to use datatables today. I have created a table. There is a height problem with that. I checked the table size with firebug. The table height is set 302px by default. I do not know how to change.I tried to change css unsuccessfully. If you help I appreciate. Thanks in advance..                                                  .dataTables_wrapper {
    clear: both;
    min-height: 302px;
    position: relative;
}

Comment: @user403295: You should make this a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the source data,
take a look to http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/table-grid
or http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/grid-table